# Pendulum in AndEngine and box2d

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

How to make a pendulum in box2d and AndEngine using Joint? Can set an example?

Comment: Please see "PhysicsRevoluteJointExample" in andEngine examples. you need to set revolute joint min angle and upper angle. and logic to set torque to negative when reached to max angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joint tutorials are all over the internet, if you want to make the pendulum swing forever, you will have to find a way to prevent it from leaking energy. Maybe monitor the momentum at a certain point and set the value every time the pendulum passes through?